# Moving files onto docker container and running them

Tags: docker, cp

I'm pretty new to docker, so I apologize if this is a simple question.  I need to create a script of some sort that will start a docker image in ubuntu:16.04, copy files from a directory onto the container, and run some of the code that was just copied in.

From what I understand, the first step would be to start up the container with something like this:

```
docker run --name test_container my_image
```

Then, I need to copy over the files.  From what I have found, this is conventionally done on the host with a command like so:

```
docker cp src/. test_container:/code/src
```

Lastly, lets say I want to run some code from my container, that I just put on it.  If I started my container with the -it tag, I could probably just do something like the following (assuming there was a makefile and hello_world.c in the src folder that was copied):

```
cd code/src/
make
./hello_world
```

But is there some way I can have this automated.  For example, I want to put the following lines in my docker file:

```
WORKDIR code/src/
RUN make
RUN ./hello_world
```

But the main problem is that if I run my dockerfile right at the beginning, I will not have my copied files on the container by the time I get to these commands at the bottom.

I was looking to see if there is a way to copy files onto the container by running commands *inside* the container.  For example:

```
RUN docker cp src/. test_container:/code/src
```

But that doesn't seem to work, which kind of makes sense.  So I was wondering if there is another good way to automate a process like this.

Comment: Can you restructure this workflow to avoid `docker cp`?  Are the "files" an application and its input data, or something else?  Think of a Docker container like a normal Linux process: you wouldn't normally first start a process, then copy its executable into it, instead you'd first build a binary (or a Docker image) and run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bake your files into the image the command is

```
COPY src /code/src/
WORKDIR /code/src
RUN make
CMD ["./hello_world"]
```

If you want to use files at runtime, you'd do it with something like

```
docker run -v $CWD/src:/code/src myimage make
```